# Pyspark: Counts based on conditions for multiple values

Tags: python, pyspark

I've been struggling with this logic for a few days. Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like this. I just made some dummy data so it might not make that much sense:

```
+----+---------------+------------+
|Id  |prescr_testdrug|diagnosis   |
+---------+----------+------------+
|0   |Yes            |[a,b,c]     |
|1   |Yes            |[b,c]       |
|2   |No             |[b,c,d]     |
|3   |Yes            |[a]         |
|4   |No             |[c,d]       |
|5   |No             |[d,e]       |
|6   |No             |[a,f]       |
|7   |Yes            |[c]         |
|8   |Yes            |[a,d,e]     |
|9   |Yes            |[a]         |
+----+---------------+------------+
```

I want to get counts based on 4 different scenarios for each of the distinct diagnosis:

Case1 = counts where patients were prescribed and diagnosed

Case2 = counts where patients were prescribed and not diagnosed

Case3 = counts where patients were not prescribed and diagnosed

Case4 = counts where patients were not prescribed and not diagnosed

I know that if I do `groupBy('diagnosis','prescr_testdrug').count()` after I do an `explode()` on diagnosis, I can basically get the counts for Case1 and Case 3 (the freq of Yes and No for each diagnosis). However I can't wrap my head around how to go about getting the values for the other two cases.

This is basically what I want my final dataframe to look like:

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+
|diagnosis|Case1 |Case2 |Case3 |Case4 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
|a        |     4|     2|     1|     3|
|b        |     2|     4|     1|     3|
|c        |     3|     3|     2|     2|
|d        |     1|     5|     2|     2|
|e        |     1|     5|     1|     3|
|f        |     0|     6|     1|     3|
+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

For example, for the first row, 4 patients were prescribed the drug AND had diagnosis 'a'; 2 patients were also prescribed the drug AND did not have diagnosis 'a'; 1 patient was not prescribed the drug AND had diagnosis 'a'; 3 patients were not prescribed with the drug AND did not have diagnoses 'a'

It feels so simple but I've just been banging my head over this for a while.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: each Id represent one patient ? Do you know all diagnosis type before?

Comment: @howie yes, the id just basically shows the distinct patients. So in the example dataframe that I show , for each patient, it shows whether or not the drug in question was prescribed(yes or no), and the list of diseases (diagnosis) that they may have been diagnosed with. I just used 'a,b,c' for simplification, but in my dataset they are actually ICD10 codes. I just don't know how to properly be able to display the counts that I want based on the 4 scenarios (Case1/2/3/4) that I outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt, you may try to write a UDF to generate not diagnosis set

**ICD10 codes total - diagnosis = not diagnosis**

```
+----+---------------+------------+-------------+
|Id  |prescr_testdrug|diagnosis   |not diagnosis|
+---------+----------+------------+-------------+
|0   |Yes            |[a,b,c]     |[d,e]        |
|1   |Yes            |[b,c]       |[a,d,e]      |
|2   |No             |[b,c,d]     |.            |
|3   |Yes            |[a]         |.            |
|4   |No             |[c,d]       |.            |
|5   |No             |[d,e]       |.            |
|6   |No             |[a,f]       |.            |
|7   |Yes            |[c]         |.            | 
|8   |Yes            |[a,d,e]     |.            |
|9   |Yes            |[a]         |.            |
+----+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

explode() by diagnosis you can get case 1 and case 3
explode() by not diagnosis you can get case 2 and case 4

Update1:

When you expose and group by diagnosis you can get the following form, but I don't know how to distint between case2 & case4.

We can get count by 
**total patient - prescr_testdrug Yes count - prescr_testdrug No count = case2 + case 4**

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|diagnosis |prescr_testdrug Yes| prescr_testdrug No| case2/case4 |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|a         |[0,3,8,9]          |[6]                |             |
|b         |[0,1]              |[2]                |             |
|c         |[0,1,7]            |[2,4]              |             |
|d         |[8]                |[4]                |             |
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my dataset has thousands of diagnosis, so if I try to create a not diagnosis set, it will be huge for each patient...

Comment: Spark is meant to process huge data, so it not a problem. But still we can try to find a better way. I will update in my answer